# Prevent inserting value greater than max at the same time restrict to decimal

Tags: javascript, html

I want to restrict the user input to two decimal places only at the same time restrict user input not greater than the maxvalue. My code below doesn't work together.

JS Code

```
var validate = function(e) {
    var t = e.value;
    e.value = (t.indexOf(".") >= 0) ? (t.substr(0, t.indexOf(".")) + t.substr(t.indexOf("."), 3)) : t;
}

var input = document.getElementById("amt");
// Add event listener
input.addEventListener("input", function(e){
    var max = parseFloat(input.max);

    this.setCustomValidity("");

    console.log(this.value)
    
    if(parseFloat(this.value) > max){
        this.value = max; 
        
    } else if(this.validity.rangeUnderflow){
        this.setCustomValidity("Does not reach the amount requirement");
    }
});
```

html code

```
<input type="number" min="100" max="999.99" step=".01" name="amt" id="amt" oninput="validate(this)" required>
```

Comment: Can you post your html too?

Comment: You have a missing `"` after `requirement`.

Comment: Just return the html code.

Comment: What is the function `this.setCustomValidity`?

Comment: sorry a typo while editing here

Comment: Can you add some test cases?

Comment: produce a custom validation message

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` at the end of addeventlistener. Next time fix your code before posting.

Comment: sorry double }. sorry for my mistake